# Passing credentials from one powershell script to another

Tags: powershell

Im trying to pass a credential to another powershell script but i get an error as

> "Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" value
>   of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential""

This is the script which invoke the psscript

```
param(
$vcenterserver,
[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]$vccredential
)


#New-Item C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1 -ItemType file -Force


#Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit -File '& 'C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1''" -vcenterserver $vcenterserver -vccredential $vccredential


Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit -File '& 'C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1''","$vcenterserver","$vccredential"
```

and here is the 1.ps1

```
param(
$vcenterserver,
$vccredential
)

Connect-VIServer $vcenterserver -Credential $vccredential


start-sleep 120
```

Comment: Why do you want to start another copy of PowerShell instead of invoking `.ps1` file in current session?

Comment: @PetSerAl, that is the requirement

Comment: Sharing credentials is a risky path. Can you explain more on how it's going to be used, ex. in the same context or on different machines by different users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method then, save the cred to disk with different key, then modify the ps1 file to load the cred from disk, like this:

First: Save the Cred to disk

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$Key = [byte]1..16
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $Key | Set-Content c:\cred.key
```

then edit the ps1 file like this for example:

```
param(
$vcenterserver
)

Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
$Key = [byte]1..16
$username = "type the username"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\cred.key | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted)

Connect-VIServer $vcenterserver -Credential $credential
```

then run it:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noExit -File c:\vcenter.ps1 -vcenterserver vcenter"
```

Comment: Beware that anyone with read access to that script has access to the key and thus to the credentials.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass a Powershell object via comand line, these will be converted to strings and become unusable. Worse, "$vccredential" returns the type name due to `toString()` implementation. You can pass a `PSCredential` object to your script if you invoke it in your current session, like this:

```
& 'C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1' $vcenterserver $vccredential
```

This way your parameters won't be converted and will retain internal structure.

If, however, you require a separate Powershell process to work with the new script, you can convert a PSCredential into two strings, namely `$cred.username` and `(ConvertFrom-SecureString $cred.password)`, which you can reassemble on the destination side via `$cred=new-object PSCredential($username,(convertto-securestring $password))`. The restriction with this process is that your other Powershell process should run under the same user account and on the same computer. But you can optionally supply the conversion cmdlets with `-key` parameter that contains 128, 192 or 256 bits (384 probably on Win8+) which will be used in AES encryption algorithm, this will allow you to run that Powershell process as another user or on another PC and use shared key to encrypt/decrypt sensitive data. As a matter of extra precaution, you can use [this module](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/11/24/saving-passwords-and-preventing-other-processes-from-decrypting-them/) to add additional "salt" (named "entropy" in that article) to your encryption, so that even intercepting the secure string and the key won't make an attacker to decrypt your data without known entropy.

Comment: if you are running the other script with the same user account in the same session you have no problem to save the credential to a variable and call it as i said in the function, if this is not the same session, you must first save the credential to disk and the load it again to a new variable, then use it, like that: 

$username = "Username"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\Cred.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted)
 of course export the cred to disk first

Comment: @Avshalom And if the user is different? Another user cannot decrypt a stored secure string, he's got different keys.

Comment: so you need to create the credential with different key, not with the default user, and then load it with the same key
ConvertTo-SecureString [-Key Byte[]]

Comment: @Avshalom And if you read the post, all of this is already inside.

Comment: @Vesper how can i launch this in a new powershell window, i need to launch & 'C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1' $vcenterserver $vccredential in a new powershell window, that is the requirement

Comment: @PowerShell You then need to split your credential into two strings. Do you have to run your next script as another user? If no, the simple naive approach will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a credential *object* in an argument *string*. Call your second script like this:

```
& 'C:\dcpromotxt\1.ps1' $vcenterserver $vccredential
```

A requirement to run the second script via `Start-Process` doesn't make sense.

Comment: of course you can't if it's a string, but if the datatype is pscredential sure you can...

Comment: @Avshalom Please read the question. Pay particular attention to how the OP is calling the second script.